# Jersey HTTP response 200 OK but returning content wrong (username/password incorrect)

Tags: java, html, rest, http, jersey

I was wondering if I wrote the Jersey client side code in the correct way.

The log-in page is supposed to redirect to main page after correct username and password input, with server side returning an empty string (`""`). If either is incorrect, server side code returns `"Username or Password are incorrect"`.

The page functionality worked well but when I was testing using my client side code using a correct pair of username and password, it returns `"Username or Password are incorrect"`, with response returning 200OK. Below is my client side code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080
                               /qa-automation-console").path("authenticate");
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("username", "username");
    form.param("password", "password");
    Response response = target.request().post(Entity.form(form));
     //The response was 200OK.
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
}
```

I suspect the username and password were not submitted in correct input positions required in HTML file. Below is the block of my HTML file.

```
 <form name="j_security_form" method="post" action="j_security_check">

  <td colspan="3" class="body"><strong>Please contact the service desk for additional 
                                              information.</strong></td>

  <td colspan="3" align="left"><p class="errorTitle"></p></td>

<span>

    <td colspan="3" align="left"><p class="subTitle1">Please log in:</p></td>

    <input class="input-small input-block" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username" 
        id="top_login" name="login" value="" autocomplete="on" type="text"></input>

    <td colspan="3" align="left"><p class="space"></p></td>

    <input class="input-small input-block" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" 
     id="top_password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="on" type="password"></input>

  </span>
  <li style="display: none;" id="message" class="login-fail hidden">Wrong username 
                                                            or password</li>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `login` instead of `username` for the post data.

Comment: Thank you. This is an issue I noticed just now. But after changing "username" to "login" the problem is still there. I am thinking about if there is an issue of "form" in my client side java code.

Comment: Does this work with curl ? maybe the j_security_check javascript function make some magic ...

Comment: How can I check whether it works with curl? The gradle (I built with gradle) command gives `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Try to perfom the post using curl or any other tool that can do the HTTP. There are browser plugin that can do the job too.

Comment: I was building the project using gradle in command line. I got an error of  `java.lang.NullPointerException`  and then `com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.trimTrailingFrom(CharMatcher.java:1242)`. What could that be?