# Jersey HTTP response 200 OK but returning content wrong (checking request)

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, httprequest

This is a follow-up question to [the one I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681218/jersey-http-response-200-ok-but-returning-content-wrong-username-password-incor).

The log-in page is supposed to redirect to main page after correct username and password input, with server side returning an empty string (`""`). If either is incorrect, server side code returns `"Username or Password are incorrect"`.

The page functionality worked well but when I was testing using my client side code using a correct pair of username and password, it returns `"Username or Password are incorrect"`, with response returning 200OK.

Below is my client side code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080
                               /qa-automation-console").path("authenticate");
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("username", "username");
    form.param("password", "password");
    Response response = target.request().post(Entity.form(form));
     //The response was 200OK.
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
}
```

Instead of other problems including HTML and Web.xml dependency, now I suspect the client code I wrote was not correct and when the request is sent it does not contain the correct username and password. The server side code is below:

```
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("authenticate")
public String authenticate(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("username") 
                      String username, @QueryParam("password") String password) 
                                                          throws Exception {
    Environments environments = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder().build();
    final ALMProfile profile = new ALMProfile();
    profile.setUrl(environments.getAutomation().getAlmProfile().getUrl());
    profile.setUsername(username);
    if ( !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(password) ) {
        String encryptedPassword = EncryptionUtils.encrypt(password);
        profile.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
    }
    try (ALMConnection connection = new ALMConnection(profile);) {
        if (connection.getOtaConnector().connected()) {
            req.getSession(true).setAttribute("username", username);
            req.getSession(true).setAttribute("password", profile.getPassword());
            return "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Username or Password are incorrect";
    }
    return "Username or Password are incorrect";
}
```

Can someone point out if the client code submits the correct request?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably need to check what's in your stack trace. And the value of `username` and `password`. I suspect them to be null.

Secondly, I think the problem is coming from the `@QueryParam` annotation.

You must use instead `@FormParam`

You use QueryParam when your url contain params as:

> www.test.com/test?username=test

When you're sending data in a Form, you must use the annotation `@FormParam`

Comment: I was building the project using gradle in command line. I got an error of `java.lang.NullPointerException` and then `com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.trimTrailingFrom(CharMatcher.java:1242)`. What could that be?

Comment: I changed the QueryParam to FormParam and the error is still there.

Comment: It's not the question you've asked. But can you post what's in line 1242 ?

Comment: Does not make a lot of sense. It is in https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java?r=f51d8fa33a59b6f817fabffbe729a8992359e15f